# running flower behind a reverse proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, celery, flower

The following is my nginx config:

```
    location /flower/ {
    rewrite /flower/(.*) /$1  break;

    sub_filter '="/' '="/flower/';
    sub_filter_last_modified on;
    sub_filter_once off;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:5555/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location /flower/static/ {
    sub_filter '/api' '/flower/api';
    sub_filter "'/monitor" "'/flower/monitor";
    sub_filter "'/worker" "'/flower/worker";
    sub_filter "'/'" "'/flower/'";
    sub_filter "'/dashboard'" "'/flower/dashboard'";
    sub_filter '"/update-dashboard"' '"/flower/update-dashboard"';
    sub_filter_types application/javascript;  # by default, sub_filter won't touch JS
    sub_filter_last_modified on;
    sub_filter_once off;

    alias <VIRTUALENV_PATH>/python3.4/site-packages/flower/static/;
    expires 30d;
}
```

Link for the above: https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/414

My flower version is 0.9.2 and nginx version is 1.12.1

I ran flower as follows:

```
$celery flower -A project_name --port=5555 --broker redis://broker_url:port
```

This renders the following:
[image]

I ran flower as follows: (used --url_prefix=flower)

```
$ celery flower -A project_name --port=5555 --broker redis://broker_url:port --url_prefix=flower
```

This then rendered all the static files as shown:
[image]

The problem occurs when I click on any of the tabs (say tasks) above as shown:
[image]

I noticed that the url instead of being say: /flower/dashboard/ is /flower/flower/dashboard and so on.

What am I missing here? Anything to be changed in nginx config?

Answer (score 2):

If flower is running like that:

```
celery --broker=amqp://broker_url:port flower --port=5555 --url_prefix=/flower
```

then nginx config requires only:

```
location /flower/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5555/flower/;
    }
```

add it should work. In my case, I used flower 1.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why are you using `sub_filter` in your nginx config.

Seems to me you are hosting flower in a particular url like `xyz.com/flower` that's why you are using `sub_filter`.

Though I have not used flower in such a way, but it seems to me wrong. There is another mistake which I could find, i.e. you are placing `location /flower/static/` below `location /flower/` hence all static requests are going to be handled by the `location /flower/` code block

You nginx config should look something like this:

```
server {
    location /flower/static {
        alias  /the/path/to/flower/static;
    }
    location /flower {
        rewrite ^/flower/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5555;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

You could read more about the settings on the [documentation](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reverse-proxy.html) and [example](https://github.com/mher/flower/tree/master/examples)

Answer (score 1):

By Changing `--url_prefix=flower` to `--url_prefix=/flower` it was fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

For docker users, here is my configuration solution :

```
# nginx.conf
upstream flower {
    server flower:8888;
}

server {
    location /flower {
        rewrite ^/flower$ /flower/;
        proxy_pass http://flower;
        allow XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And

```
# docker-compose.yml
flower:  
    image: mher/flower
    command: celery flower --url_prefix=/flower
    environment:
        - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
        - FLOWER_PORT=8888
    expose:
        - 8888
```

Inspired by @Polieter answer.